# How to allow external traffic to call Firebase Functions behind VPC Network

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-functions, google-vpc

A third-party vendor requires an IP address for our Firebase Functions so that they can whitelist them.

**Current Stack**

- React Native
- Firebase (functions, admin)

**What we've done**

We have created a VPC Network and a connector following this documentation https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/connecting-vpc using the Google Cloud Console.

We have our VPC Network, Connector and have added one of our Firebase Functions to that connector.

Here is our Firebase Function Connection settings. You can see here we allow all ingress traffic.

[image: Function Config]

**The Problem**

However, when we try to invoke the function via Postman, it timesout and I don't see any errors in our logs. Currently, I have selected to allow all ingress traffic to go through our VPC Network for this function.

My best guess now is that the default firewall for this network is blocking all external traffic, per this message in Google Cloud.

[image: Firebase Firewall Message]

**Here's my question:**

1. How can we allow all external traffic to hit our function in the VPC Network via the VPC Network's Firewall config? I want to be able to invoke it from Postman as well as our app. But both are timing out.
2. Once this is working, which IP address should I use to whitelist this function? I see an option to create my own static IP address but each subnet for my network also has ranges for our region. Should we use one of those instead?

If needed, I'd be happy to share our network and connector settings if that is helpful. DevOps is not our strong suite so really just need help on finishing this up.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi, Are you still having this issue?